# How do I POST JSON data object to server in iOS5?

Tags: json, http, post, ios5, webserver

I want to send a new object created on iOS to a receiving server with a `POST` method using `JSON` data type. From what I know about receiving data **from** the server in iOS, is that all `JSON` handling was simplified by Apple with the introduction of iOS 5. But in contradistinction to GETting JSON objects, POSTing those isn't really described anywhere I could find ...

The first steps I took to try and solve the problem looked as follows:

```
    //build an info object and convert to json
    NSDictionary *newDatasetInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:name, @"name", language, @"language", nil];

    //convert object to data
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:newDatasetInfo options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:someURLSetBefore];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    // any other things to set in request? or working this way?

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    // What to do with NSURLConnection? Or how to send differently?
```

But I really don't know how to **send a JSON object to a server using a POST method** at all.
Could anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I worked it out by trying a bit around, here's my code:

```
    //build an info object and convert to json
    NSDictionary *newDatasetInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:name, @"name", language, @"language", nil];

    //convert object to data
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:newDatasetInfo options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:someURLSetBefore];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    // print json:
    NSLog(@"JSON summary: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
```

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on what is happening in your code? I have used it in my own app now, but I honestly don't know that much about what it's doing. I understand the dictionary and turning it into data for JSON, but everything with the URLRequest and the URLConnection is unknown for me. Any clarification would be great!

Comment: An NSURLRequest is basically an object to set the properties of your web fetch. In normal fetches you would have the most used defaults set automatically, but as I want to send data I want to use the HTTP POST method and cause I want to receive a JSON object I'm telling the server this by setting the Content-Type and Accept HTTP header fields to JSON format. To learn more about the HTTP protocol and especially the HTTP header just search for them or read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields.

Comment: To learn more about NSURLConnection I think the best way is to just read its class reference in Apples Documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html. In general I can only encourage you to first have a look into Apples documentation first, as it is a great (and definitely up-to-date) source for learning these things.

Comment: Oh, of course I meant that I want to *send* a JSON object, not receive. The editing time's over already ... :(

Comment: @CGee For the error:&error do you just declare a NSError and set it to nil above? Because I tried that and its just crashes??

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)txtFetchData2:(id)sender {
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/username.php?name=%@", [self.txtName text]];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest
                          requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                          queryString]
                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSDictionary* jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"Value1", @"Key1",
                                @"Value2", @"Key2",
                                nil];
NSError *error;
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary
                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
// should check for and handle errors here but we aren't
[theRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        //do something with error
    } else {
        NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseText);

        NSString *newLineStr = @"\n";
        responseText = [responseText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br />" withString:newLineStr];            
        [self.lblData setText:responseText];
    }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSString *strUrl = @"URL";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];

// For set postdata in string
NSString *strPatientID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",self.txtDegit1.text,self.txtDegit2.text,self.txtDegit3.text,self.txtDegit4.text];
NSString *deviceToken = @"";
postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"practiceid=%@&email=%@&password=%@&devicetoken=%@",strPatientID,self.txtUsername.text,self.txtPassword.text,deviceToken];


NSMutableData *httpDataBody = [NSMutableData data];
[httpDataBody appendData:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *strPostLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[httpDataBody length]];

if ([httpDataBody length ] > 0){

    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:strPostLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:httpDataBody];

}

urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[urlConnection start];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://webstar52.com/demo/webcommunity/work.php"]]];
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&tag=%@&user_id=%@",@"getcontact",@"10408"]; 
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];      
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
  conn  = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```